# Cannot view SQL Server Agent in SSMS v17

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

I'm logged into two accounts. The SA account and my personal account. On my SA account, I can see the SQL Server Agent node, and on the other I cannot. They are both connecting to the exact same server and instance.

In my personal user properties I have all roles including SQLAgentOperatorRole, SQLAgentReaderRole and SQLAgentUserRole checked. I'm also a sysadmin.

[image]

Comment: Is your windows account setup as a user directly, or are you adding it as part of a group? If part of a group, try adding it directly and see if that solves your problem. If it does then recheck all of your permissions on the group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting my profile in MSSQL and recreating it to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

You should run the SSMS as admin. Then Agent will appear.

Comment: Note that Agent does appear, but not for both logins. Assuming the OP correctly reported their situation, their personal login has `sysadmin` rights on the instance in question. Are you saying that, in the same situation, you've seen the "sa" account show the agent, and other accounts with `sysadmin` rights *not* show the agent, and fixed that by running SSMS as administrator?